# Randomly permute numbers {1, 2 ... n} what is the prob. digit k ends up in the i'th position

Tags: probability

Let's fix the position of digit k. We now can permute other (n-1) digits. The number of permutations is (n-1)!

So the probability is $\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}$

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability is (I  think clearly) $\frac{1}{n}$. For the number $k$ is equally likely to end up in any one of the positions.

One can also conclude this in a more complicated way. There are $n!$ equally likely permutations of our $n$ numbers. By your reasoning, there are $(n-1)!$ permutations that are "favourable," meaning that the number $k$ ends up in the $i$-th position. So the required probability is $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$, which simplifies to $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: This is such a simple problem. And now I'm ashamed that I've asked it :(

Comment: At first this sort of problem can seem difficult. After a while the answer becomes obvious. Going through the transition is how one develops intuition.